# email contents parsing get email address on shell script

Tags: parsing, shell, email, sed, grep

```
in folder 
asdasdasd.msg
asdasd.msg
twadasf.msg
...
...
...
```

*.msg file Sample Email Contents =>

```
Date: Wed, 03 Aug 2011 11:20:59 +0300 (EEST)
From: Email Account Name =?utf-8?B?R8OcTkRPxJ5EVQ==?= <emailname@sample.com>
To: Different Email Account Name  <different@sample.com>
Subject: Re: Web Anketi
Message-ID: <d6d75689-bfde-451d-8a91-0da4d4e8921e@posta.sample.com>
In-Reply-To: <4ac9813a-4511-4530-b098-62fd23ecdb5b@posta.sample.com>
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Originating-IP: [10.199.16.77]
....
```

run.sh script:

```
    for line in `sed 's/\(<\)\(.*\)\(@sample.com>\)/\2/'` *.msg
    do 
        echo $line
    done
```

*my problem is getting email address List *@sample.com?

get all email address array list?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a bash for loop to read all *.msg files. `sed -n` suppresses output of all non-matches for the pattern. The `p` flag at end of the sed command prints out the substituted text.

```
for file in *.msg
do 
    sed -n 's/^.*\(<\)\(.*\)\(@posta.sample.com>\)/\2/p' $file
done
```

Comment: thanks man :) 

how to result to define ArrayList variables ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do. bash arrays are simple to use, or store the results in a file. If you get stuck, you would be best served by asking another question on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

thanks man :)

is worked code

```
for file in *.msg
do 
    sed -n 's/^.*\(<\)\(.*\)\(@posta.sample.com>\)/\2/p' $file
done
```

how to result to define ArrayList variables ?